# How do I make a random int into a variable I can use and compare in Java?

Tags: java, random, dice

its not great code I know but I need help at line 30 with if (guess == roll) im trying to make it if you guess the number right it will say you win and if not it will not say you win.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class diceGame 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    diceGame test = new diceGame();
     
    System.out.println("Number of rolls?: ");
    int numRoll = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Gues the number/most common number: ");
    int guess = scan.nextInt();
     
     Random rand = new Random();
    
            for(int i = 0; i < roll.length; i++)
            {
            roll[i] = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
            }
            
        for(int i = 0; i < roll.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.print(roll[i] + ", ");
        }
 
        
        if (guess == roll)
        {
            System.out.println("Good job you guess correct");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You did not guess correct");
        }
 } 
    
 }
```

Comment: 1)  you can't compare `guess`, which is an `int` with `roll`, which is (presumably) a `int[]`. 2) where is `roll` declared?

Comment: You are making 6 rolls. So you need to compare your guess with one of the 6 rolls. In fact, you only need to store 1 roll instead of 6 rolls (which I am not sure why you did so).

Comment: you can change however many rolls you need or want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to guess the number with the highest frequency after n number of rolls, you can update the **count of each roll** into an array instead of storing the roll outcome of each roll into the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < roll.length; i++)
{
    roll[rand.nextInt(6)]++;   //store count of each roll
}
```

To find out if you guessed the most frequency roll, find the maximum value (most commonly rolled number) of the array:

```
int maxIdx = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < roll.length; i++)
{
    if(roll[i] > roll[maxIdx])
        maxIdx = i;
}
```

To compare your guess against the most common number:

```
if (guess == maxIdx+1)  //+1 to maxIdx to offset array start index
{
    System.out.println("Good job you guess correct");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("You did not guess correct");
}
```

Comment: This works great but for some reason the only numbers are 0 1 2

Comment: which numbers are 0 1 2?

Comment: i mean, instead of the dice displaying numbers 1-6 it only displays 0-2

Comment: I got it to work! thanks so fuckin much dude it means alot for a newbie like me